# Cannot Create User Object in grails 2.1.1 using Spring Security

Tags: grails, spring-security, grails-2.0

I have the following class

```
class SentryUser {

    transient springSecurityService

    String userName
    String password
    boolean enabled
    boolean accountExpired = false
    boolean accountLocked = false
    boolean passwordExpired   = false

    static constraints = {
        userName blank: false, unique: true
        password blank: false
    }

    static mapping = {
        password column: '`password`'
    }

    Set<SentryRole> getAuthorities() {
        SentryUserSentryRole.findAllBySentryUser(this).collect { it.sentryRole } as Set
    }

    def beforeInsert() {
        encodePassword()
    }

    def beforeUpdate() {
        if (isDirty('password')) {
            encodePassword()
        }
    }

    protected void encodePassword() {
        password = springSecurityService.encodePassword(password)
    }
}
```

I'm calling the following code in bootstrap

```
def admin = new SentryUser(userName: "sample@sample.com",
                enabled: true).save(failOnError: true)
```

and getting the following error

```
context.GrailsContextLoader Error executing bootstraps: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SentryUser.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

I'm on grails 2.1.1 and using the spring security plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `save(Map)` but the MME is complaining about `save()` with no arguments. I've seen this discrepancy before when I didn't have any persistence plugins (hibernate/mongodb) installed in my application - it was a plugin project that I was trying to run as a standalone app and the default BuildConfig for a new plugin project doesn't include a dependency on hibernate.

Comment: That was the reason... I had to add hibernate to my project and that did the trick